# Subclassing with CoreData and UITableviewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to subclass UITableViewController to minimize my code.

Basically I have all code in the super class exempt for the FetchedResultController, which I override in my subclasses.

It worked without this "split" but now it returns an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.

Here is the code in my subclass:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
    {
        if (super.fetchedResultsController != nil)
        {
            return super.fetchedResultsController;
        }
        id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question" inManagedObjectContext:[delegate managedObjectContext]];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

        NSSortDescriptor*sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"up_vote_count" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        //next line returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[delegate managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root2"];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        super.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        return super.fetchedResultsController;
    }
```

I'm curious if I should use *super.* or *self.* but *self.* crashed in the if statement.

-- EDIT --

Here is the @interface of the superclass. My subclass doesn't contain anything except of the overwritten methods.

```
@interface CoreDataTableView : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {  


 }

 - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
 @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> self. crashed in the if statement

That is because you're recursively calling the `fetchedResultsController` method into an infinite loop.

Now, there are a few other problems.

First, I would suggest splitting that method into 2 parts:

1. initializing the fetched results controller
2. fetching the data

Also, your `fetchRequest` is never released. Nor is `aFetchedResultsController`. You own both of these objects inside that method, so you must release them to prevent leaks.

Based on these remarks, here's how the code would look:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    // In this method, because it's overriding the accessor in the super-class,
    // you must use |super.fetchedResultsController|, 
    // otherwise you will trigger an infinite loop!

    if (super.fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return super.fetchedResultsController;
    }
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // ...

    // omitted the other details...       

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[delegate managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root2"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    super.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    return super.fetchedResultsController;
}


- (void)fetch
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    // using |self| here is OK, because you're referring to the current object's method
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }        
}
```

As for using `super` vs `self`:

- `super.foo` or `[super foo]` starts to look for method `foo` in the
  super-class
- `self.foo` or `[self foo]` looks for method `foo` in the
  current object's class

In your case, it wouldn't make much difference except for the fact that `self.fetchedResultsController` would trigger an infinite loop as I mentioned before, if used inside the accessor.

I hope I got this right and that it cleared things up for you...

Comment: Thanks! Release is not allowed in ARC though, so I removed it. It doesn't crash anymore, although the method config cell is never called. The app crashes at launch if I put a NSLog in the cellForRowattIndexPath (in superclass), weird. The line it points to is in the managed object class (which worked perfectly before).

Comment: From what I can see no tableview delegate methods are getting called in the superclass. Do I need a xib interface or declare a UITableView in it?

Comment: I would be able to answer your question if I saw the @interface declaration of your TableViewController. Could you post that code? Either way, a UITableViewController requires a UITableView to display the data. No matter how you define that table view (via code or in a XIB file), make sure you set both its UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource to point to the UITableViewController.

Comment: Im away from the computer for some weeks now, so I can't show you the code. However the subclass contained no methods I believe, and the super the standard core data tableview from apples template. Yes, it needs a tableview, but do I have to create it, or will the uitableviewcontroller class do that?

Comment: Yes, you're responsible for creating the tableView and setting its delegates.